# React Native Navigation 5.x NavigationInjectedProps

Tags: react-native

I am currently switching to navigation 5.x from 4.x. I'm using

```
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from 'react-navigation'
```

across the entire application, but I cannot find anything equivalent in navigation 5. I'm using typescript.

Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the logic behind obtaining params is changed. In v5, you have to access them from a `route`, which is passed as an additional property for class components, unlike using `navigation` in the previous versions.

To type your params in the right way, you have to type the route. For previously written code:

```
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from 'react-navigation'

type Params = {
  param1: string
}

type Props = NavigationInjectedProps<Params>

class MyComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { param1 } = this.props.navigation.state.params
  }
}
```

the rough equivalent will be:

```
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'

type RootParamsList = {
  MyComponent: {
    param1: string
  }
}

type Props = StackScreenProps<RootParamsList, 'MyComponent'>

class MyComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { param1 } = this.props.route.params.param1
    return null
  }
}
```